# PHP DateTime: Failed to parse time string

Tags: php, string, parsing, datetime

I've looked at other questions about the same error but I'm having trouble applying them to my situation.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse
>   time string (2013-07-22164:50:00) at position 10 (1): Unexpected
>   character' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Festival_Planner/index.php:88
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Festival_Planner/index.php(88):
>   DateTime->__construct('2013-07-22164:5...', Object(DateTimeZone)) #1
>   {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Festival_Planner/index.php on
>   line 88

This is the for loop with the line that's generating the error:

```
    for($iCount2=0;$iCount2<count($ascreenings);$iCount2++){
    $ocurrentscreening = $ascreenings[$iCount2];

    ///////// THIS IS LINE 88:
    $time = new DateTime($ocurrentscreening->date.''.$ocurrentscreening->starttime,new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland'));
    $displayTime = date_format($time, 'g:ia');

    $sLabel =  $ocurrentscreening->date.', '.$displayTime.'.';
    $oForm->makeCheckBox("screening".$ocurrentscreening->screeningid, $sLabel, $ocurrentscreening->screeningid);
        }
```

And this is a similar for loop that DOES work, using exactly the same code structure as I did on line 88.

```
    for($iCount=0;$iCount<count($aUsersScreenings);$iCount++){
        $odisplayedscreening = $aUsersScreenings[$iCount];

        $ofilm = new film();
        $ofilm->load($odisplayedscreening->filmid);

        $title = $ofilm->title;

        $time = new DateTime($odisplayedscreening->date.''.$odisplayedscreening->starttime,new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland'));
        $displayTime = date_format($time, 'g:ia');

        $sHTML .= '
        <div class="selected" id="screening'.$odisplayedscreening->screeningid.'"> 
        <span>'.$title.'</span>.'.$displayTime.'.
        </div>
        ';
        }
```

Comment: It tells you everything clearly.. `to parse time string (2013-07-22164:50:00) at position 10 (1): Unexpected character`. Take a look at that string, the year and time are glued together and it's obviously malformed. It's not the code but the input. DateTime class another method called `createFromFormat` where you can specify input format no matter how weird it seems. Also, why do you use a DateTime object and the `date_format` function if you have `$time->format('g:ia')` available?

Comment: Got it, I'd inputted a time string in my database incorrectly. That's embarrassing ... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a space between date and time

```
$time = new DateTime($ocurrentscreening->date.' '.$ocurrentscreening->starttime,new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland'));
```